# Need assistance regarding using the xep-0184

Tags: objective-c, ios, xmpp, xmppframework

I am using [robbiehanson/XMPPFramework](https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework/) for my current project, I can send and receive messages to people in my roster, but now I have to implement message delivery status. I know the xep its 0184 and I have also included in my project, I am having difficulty utilizing it.

I read in [xep-0184 document](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0184.html) that request element must also included in message, so here is my code:

```
#import "XMPPMessage+XEP_0184.h"
.
.
.
NSXMLElement *body = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"body"];

[body setStringValue:messageStr];

NSXMLElement *request = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"request" xmlns:@"urn:xmpp:receipts"];

NSXMLElement *message = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"message"];

[message addAttributeWithName:@"type" stringValue:@"chat"];

[message addAttributeWithName:@"to" stringValue:[defaults objectForKey:@"chatWith"]]; 
[message addChild:body];
[message addChild:request];
.
.
.
XMPPMessage *xm = [[XMPPMessage alloc]init];
NSLog(@"..1..%d",[xm hasReceiptRequest]);        // Result = 0
NSLog(@"..2..%d",[xm hasReceiptResponse]);       // Result = 0
NSLog(@"..3..%@",[xm extractReceiptResponseID]); // Result = (null)
NSLog(@"..4..%@",[xm generateReceiptResponse]);  // Result = <message><received xmlns="urn:xmpp:receipts"></received></message>
```

Please help how do i get a message delivery status.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the message delivary status using XMPP framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20852336/how-to-get-the-message-delivary-status-using-xmpp-framework)

Answer (score 2):

I think you forgot to add the module itself.
When you want to add an XMPPModule like XMPPMessageDeliveryReceipts you should add it to the XMPPStream object first, then you can use its functions.

Do the following:

```
// Setup Message Delivery Recipts Object
XMPPMessageDeliveryReceipts* xmppMessageDeliveryRecipts = [[XMPPMessageDeliveryReceipts alloc] initWithDispatchQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
xmppMessageDeliveryRecipts.autoSendMessageDeliveryReceipts = YES;
xmppMessageDeliveryRecipts.autoSendMessageDeliveryRequests = YES;

[xmppMessageDeliveryRecipts activate:xmppStream];
```

When xmppStream is your main XMPPFramework object.

Hope i helped.

Comment: Can you explain in details of it. Because even though we implemented Delivery Notification over XMPP Stream, We are unable to receive any notifications.  Please share more information regarding Delivery Notifications

Comment: Hey, have a look here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20852336/how-to-get-the-message-delivary-status-using-xmpp-framework?lq=1
It might help you a little more.