# How to get the message delivary status using XMPP framework

Tags: ios, xmppframework

I am using the XMPP Framework for chatting between the users , Chatting is happening perfectly .Now I need to show the message is delivered perfectly to both devices like (What's app messenger). I am not getting any tutorial to follow. Below code represents while we send message to the other user.

```
//Sending the message to the other user
 NSXMLElement *body = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"body"];
 [body setStringValue:txtChat.text];

 NSXMLElement *message = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"message"];
 [message addAttributeWithName:@"type" stringValue:@"chat"];
 [message addAttributeWithName:@"to" stringValue:self.userjid];
 [message addChild:body];
 [[APPDELEGATE xmppStream] sendElement:message];
```

While reterving the message by using XMPP Framework i was getting the data by using below code

```
- (void)loadarchivemsg
{        
    XMPPMessageArchivingCoreDataStorage *storage = [XMPPMessageArchivingCoreDataStorage sharedInstance];
    NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [storage mainThreadManagedObjectContext];
    NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"XMPPMessageArchiving_Message_CoreDataObject"
                                                         inManagedObjectContext:moc];
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(bareJidStr like %@) && (streamBareJidStr like %@)", self.userjid,[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"kXMPPmyJID"]];
    request.predicate = predicate;
    NSLog(@"%@",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"kXMPPmyJID"]);
    [request setEntity:entityDescription];
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *messages_arc = [moc executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

    [self print:[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:messages_arc]];    
}

- (void)print:(NSMutableArray*)messages_arc{
    @autoreleasepool {
        for (XMPPMessageArchiving_Message_CoreDataObject *message in messages_arc) {

            NSXMLElement *element = [[NSXMLElement alloc] initWithXMLString:message.messageStr error:nil];
            XMPPMessage *message12=[[XMPPMessage alloc]init];
            message12 = [message message];
  }
}
```

In this why I was sending the message and retrieving the message,can you help me how to retrieve the delivery status of the message . Waiting for your valuable answers.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

@Romance you need to add below code  in the connect method

```
  XMPPMessageDeliveryReceipts* xmppMessageDeliveryRecipts = [[XMPPMessageDeliveryReceipts alloc] initWithDispatchQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
    xmppMessageDeliveryRecipts.autoSendMessageDeliveryReceipts = YES;
    xmppMessageDeliveryRecipts.autoSendMessageDeliveryRequests = YES;
    [xmppMessageDeliveryRecipts activate:self.xmppStream];
```

Remember to add these line while sending message

```
NSString *messageID=[self.xmppStream generateUUID];

        NSXMLElement *message = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"message"];
        [message addAttributeWithName:@"id" stringValue:messageID];
        [message addAttributeWithName:@"type" stringValue:@"chat"];
        [message addAttributeWithName:@"to" stringValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"senderJabberID_Here"]];

        [message addChild:body];
```

Hope this help you :)

Comment: Thanks for your Reply .I was used your code as per flow you provided,but now i am having doubt that how to know the message deliverd or not .In response how can i identify.can you provide some code.thank you for responding @Rohit Pathak

Comment: SENT MESSAGE STANZA <message id="7D4A1379-4FF3-424B-AE00-46F8B45F1D94" type="chat" to="user_5@localhost"><body>Hey yo</body><request xmlns="urn:xmpp:receipts"></request></message>

RECEIVE MESSAGE STANZA <message xmlns="jabber:client" from="user_5@localhost/Smack" to="user_4@localhost/25696800891388665287783924" id="AXRzR-12"><received xmlns="urn:xmpp:receipts" id="7D4A1379-4FF3-424B-AE00-46F8B45F1D94"></received></message>



LOOK IN THE RECEIVE MESSAGE STANZA YOUR GOT <received> tag with the same message ID you sent that

Comment: If this help you please make +1 to the answer so that it would help others also

Comment: I will accept it dear but now i am getting my response <message id="8305E6DA-F7A8-4739-8AE4-19B2F963C529" type="chat" to="user@hostname"><body>hello</body><amp xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/amp">action</amp><request xmlns="urn:xmpp:receipts"></request></message> like this.i didnt find the received tag in response.

Comment: RECEIVE MESSAGE STANZA is not coming,please tell me where i was going wrong.I was getting SENT MESSAGE STANZA .How to get Recevie

Comment: If you are not receive RECEIVE MESSAGE STANZA it means the other user would not set xmppMessageDeliveryRecipts.autoSendMessageDeliveryReceipts = YES;

Please check the code of sender also

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44390/discussion-between-romance-and-rohit-pathak)

Comment: Can you please tell me how i would be getting response by activating delivery receipts? Will there be any delegate method that will be called which will notify us that the message has been delivered successfully. If yes please let me know the method name or the event where i will get the success event.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: @RahulMathur you got something like this <message xmlns="jabber:client" from="user_5@localhost/Smack" to="user_4@localhost/25696800891388665287783924" id="AXRzR-12"><received xmlns="urn:xmpp:receipts" id="7D4A1379-4FF3-424B-AE00-46F8B45F1D94"></received></message>  In your didreceivemessage delegate

Comment: hi @RohitPathak actually am receiving like above.. but same message means receiving Delivery Status so many times... any solution

Comment: @RohitPathak how do you notified in iOS for Delivery Status? means i am sending message but message sent or not that i need. I have implemented "XMPPMessageDeliveryReceipts" code. but where its methods call back i can get for read/ unread status

Comment: @RohitPathak I have implemented this feature and working successfully. I am confused how to decide message is delivered or read? Because there is not any provision to store message status delivery. Can you please suggest me what do I need to do?

Comment: @JayeshSojitra xmpp do not provide any receipt for read message status, whenever you got the RECEIVED RECEIPT like this 

<received xmlns="urn:xmpp:receipts" id="7D4A1379-4FF3-424B-AE00-46F8B45F1D94"></received>

Its only indicates the delivery of the XMPP message of above id in the receipt tag.

Comment: hey @RohitPathak i am having the same issue,i am getting  <message type="chat" to="tc_1@tam.com" from="tu11_0@tam.com" timestamp="2016-02-05 11:02:52 +0530" id="EB0DD19D-AA68-4F54-9084-779318EEA5F4"><active xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates"></active><body>Hjj</body><request xmlns="urn:xmpp:receipts"></request></message>  if the message is received by the receiver  then also i am getting the sent stanza in all messages , also in offline storage mode i am getting sent stanza only.Do i have to add sumthing when receiver recive the message in didrecivemessage method?

Comment: @FeminaBrahmbhatt when you need to enable xmppMessageDeliveryRecipts.autoSendMessageDeliveryReceipts = YES;
xmppMessageDeliveryRecipts.autoSendMessageDeliveryRequests = YES;