# Read receipt in iOS XMPP chat application

Tags: ios, xmpp

i would want to implement" read message feature"like  like Facebook, iMessage,WhatsApp etc.
If receiver has read the message , sender will get a notification that the other person has read message.

Is there any protocol in xMPP for this feature ?

if sender sends the message and if it is successfully delivered there is a xmpp protocol . Got it from link:
 [How to get the message delivary status using XMPP framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20852336/how-to-get-the-message-delivary-status-using-xmpp-framework?rq=1)

Following is the code to get delivery report.

```
XMPPMessageDeliveryReceipts* xmppMessageDeliveryRecipts = [[XMPPMessageDeliveryReceipts alloc] initWithDispatchQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
xmppMessageDeliveryRecipts.autoSendMessageDeliveryReceipts = YES;
xmppMessageDeliveryRecipts.autoSendMessageDeliveryRequests = YES;
[xmppMessageDeliveryRecipts activate:self.xmppStream];
```

But i want to receive read receipt. Please help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[XEP-0085](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0085.html) "active" chatstate basically used as "read receipt"

Comment: To me chat states seem to be a completely separate function to read receipts.